# Unable to format USB due to old file corruption

Tags: usb, formatting, filesystem-corruption

I accidentally corrupted some files on a 4GB USB when I tried to install extensions and apps to a portable version of google chrome. I tried to format the USB, and it failed partway through the format. Now the drive only says FAT32 where it should list the disk space. Is there a way to resolve this in Windows? I don't have a USB to run a linux distribution like PartedMagic.

Comment: maybe there's a program to delete partitions from usb stick.

Comment: I've tried fixing it in GParted live distribution, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following these steps to fix your USB:

1. Plug in your USB drive.
2. Open the Command Prompt as admin (Windows key + x, then choose "Command Prompt (Admin)").
3. Type in "diskpart"
4. Then type "list disk".
5. After that, look for your USB's "Disk ###", and then type in "select disk x", where "x" is the number of your disk.
6. Then type in "clean".
7. After, type in "create partition primary".
8. Type in "exit", then close the window.
9. Your USB drive should be fixed!

Hope that helped!

Comment: Wow it worked! I've spent so long trying to fix this and your solution helped fix it! I ran your instructions and then successfully formatted the disk. It works now; thanks so much!